# Flattening a nested Lazy List that may or not have children with FP-TS or Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, fp-ts

I just learned about lift and applicatives and on my quest to trying to understand these structures I am trying to implement a real use case.

I have a List (array) that is lazy, meaning that I can't get the count of items or their children until I load it. getting the nodes and loading it is async, same for its nested children (if any).

so if I would have the structure below:

```
[{title:"test1",children:[]},{title:"test2",children:[{title:"test2_1",children:[]}]}]
```

For each one of the children I don't know if they have children until I load the node and check the children count.

How could I check the entire list with FP (regardless of how nested it can go) either:

-By loading and checking each node at the time. and stop when we find a match or run out of nodes.

or

-By loading all nodes then (probably nesting it into Rights() and Lefts()), flattening into a single list, then foldmapping for a item by title with a predicate just like in the example below.

This is what I know works for the first match of a element in a non nested array:

```
[{title:"test1"},{title:"test2"},{title:"test3"}] //structure we are loading

const find= (l,f)=>l.foldMap(x=>First(f(x)?Right(x):Left()),First.empty())

const nodes = await getNodes() //not gonna even put in a type just to illustrate that getting and loading the nodes is async. 
const list = List(await load(nodes)) //not gonna even put in a type just to illustrate that getting and loading the nodes is async. 

console.log(find(list,x=>x.title==='test3').fold(x=>x).fold(console.error,x=>x))
```

Edit: current imperative working code:

This is a sharepoint code that will get all nested navigation nodes from the globalNav. The important thing is I want to understand how I can turn this into a FP implementation preferable using applicatives.

```
GetNavigationNodeChildren = node => node.get_children();
GetNavigationNodeRoot = spCtx => spCtx.get_web()
  .get_navigation().get_topNavigationBar();
ExecQuery = spCtx => resource => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => spCtx.executeQueryAsync(
    () => res(resource),
    (s, a) => rej({ s, a }),
  ));
};
LoadResource = spCtx => resource => (spCtx.load(resource) ? resource : resource);
LoadAndExec = spCtx => async resource => {
    LoadResource(spCtx)(resource )
    await ExecQuery(spCtx)(resource )
    return resource
}
getAll = spCtx=> async resource=> {
    return {node:await LoadAndExec(spCtx)(resource),children:await hasChildren(c)(resource.get_children())}
}
hasChildren = spCtx => async resource => {
    LoadResource(spCtx)(resource )
    await ExecQuery(spCtx)(resource )
    return Promise.all(resource.get_count()>0?resource.get_objectData().$1G_0.map(await getAll(spCtx)):[])
}

c=new SP.ClientContext()
root=GetNavigationNodeRoot(c)
await LoadAndExec(c)(root)
all=await hasChildren(c)(root)
```

PS: Look... The idea is to learn and understand FP, please if all you have to say is that I don't need to change the code/I am making it complicated... That is really not the point of the question.

Comment: What do you mean with lazy? Are the promises not yet created or are they just pending? Btw. an arbitrarily nested list is also called a rose or n-ary tree. And since you mentioned applicative: In the context of async computations applicative means running in parallel (more precisely concurrenty). Monads on the other hand run in sequence.

Comment: Hi, lazy meaning that the data of the nested element will have to be loaded and will return a callback/promise as result. Yes either monands or applicatives would work I think, I just don't know how to put that computation together using FP structures.
The idea that I had is that if I use monands I eventually will nest types and unwrap one by one foldmapping each item and it's children if any. for the applicative would be the same but instead we will load all nested nodes in parallel and get the first found element.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to handle the async effect applicatively, right? You shouldn't fixate on applicative/monad though. Start with the primitives (`and`, `or`) of an async type (let's call it `Parallel`) that implements applicative. Both primitives run its to arguments in parallel. From there you could derive two monoid instances (race from `or` and one instance from `and` that appends the results of two async operations). Then you can think about implementing a fold that uses the monoid to append arbitrarily many `Parallel` values stored in some data structure.

Comment: You only need applicative if you need to apply a pure function to two or more `Parallel` values. Please note that `Parallel` cannot be a monad, b/c it is parallel. You can implement a type that works in-parallel while used as an applicative and in-sequence while used as a monad, but such an approach is frowned upon.

Comment: I added some working imperative code so you can all understand what I have working. But I still can't view the same code in a FP applicative/monad implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to retrieve all the children of a nested root navigation node:

```ts
import * as T from 'fp-ts/Task'

// Something like this

interface NavigationNode {
  readonly title: string
}

declare const getNavChildren: (node: NavigationNode) => T.Task<NavigationNode[]>

const flattenNavNode = (node: NavigationNode): T.Task<readonly NavigationNode[]> => {
  // ... do something with getNavChildren to flatten the node
}
```

A [`Task<A>`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Task.ts.html) is simply `() => Promise<A>`, that is, a function that returns a Promise. This represents an asynchronous side effect.

---

One way you could implement `flattenNavNode` is like this:

```ts
import * as RA from 'fp-ts/ReadonlyArray'
import {flow, pipe} from 'fp-ts/function'

const flattenNavNode = (node: NavigationNode): T.Task<readonly NavigationNode[]> =>
  pipe(
    getNavChildren(node),                     // 1
    T.chain(T.traverseArray(flattenNavNode)), // 2
    T.map(flow(RA.flatten, RA.prepend(node))) // 3
  )
```

`pipe` pipes a value through multiple functions (`pipe(a, ab, bc)` is equivalent to `bc(ab(a))`). Let’s go through this function pipeline (I’ve omitted some `readonly`s for brevity):

1. Get the children of the navigation node. We now have a `Task<NavigationNode[]>`.
2. This is the recursive part. We want to get *all* the children at all depths, so we must flatten out each one of the children from the original node.

   Getting the children of the children is going be asynchronous and return some `Task`, but the array of children is wrapped up in a `Task` already from step 1, so we use `chain`:

   ```ts
   declare const chain: <A, B>(f: (a: A) => Task<B>) => (ma: Task<A>) => Task<B>
   ```

   This is analogous to using `flatMap` on an array.

   Inside the `T.chain` we have a `NavigationNode[]`. You might think of using `RA.map(flattenNavNode)` to get the children of each node, but that would result in a `Task<NavigationNode[]>[]` (`Array<Task<...>>`) and we need to return a `Task` directly from `chain`.

   `T.traverseArray` allows us to return a `Task<NavigationNode[][]>` (`Task<Array<...>>`) instead:

   ```ts
   declare const traverseArray: <A, B>(f: (a: A) => Task<B>) => (as: readonly A[]) => Task<readonly B[]>
   ```

   This executes the `Task`s in parallel (`T.traverseArray(f)(xs)` is analogous to `Promise.all(xs.map(f))`), which is the default in fp-ts. `T.traverseSeqArray` will traverse the array sequentially, which is probably not what you want.

   This is a specialised and more efficient variant of `traverse`, which comes from [`Traversable`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Traversable.ts.html).
3. It looks like we’re almost done — we need a `Task<NavigationNode[]>`, and we have a `Task<NavigationNode[][]>`. However, we haven’t included the original `node` in this array, and we also need to flatten the result.

   First, we use `T.map` to work on the `NavigationNode[][]` inside the `Task`. Using `flow`, which is left-to-right function composition, we first `RA.flatten` the array of arrays, and then `RA.prepend` the original node to the flattened array.

---

A different way of going about it is to use a (rose) [`Tree`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Tree.ts.html).

```ts
type Forest<A> = Array<Tree<A>>

interface Tree<A> {
  readonly value: A
  readonly forest: Forest<A>
}
```

fp-ts even comes with [`unfoldTreeM`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Tree.ts.html#unfoldtreem) that allows you to build a tree in the context of a monad:

```ts
import {pipe} from 'fp-ts/function'
import type {Tree} from 'fp-ts/Tree'

const navNodeToTree = (node: NavigationNode): T.Task<Tree<NavigationNode>> =>
  unfoldTreeM(
    T.Monad // use the Task monad
  )(
    node, // root node
    // Type annotations not necessary but I added them for clarity
    (node: NavigationNode): T.Task<[value: A, forest: A[]]> =>
      pipe(
        getChildren(node),
        T.map(children => [node, children])
      )
  )
```

Then you could flatten the tree:

```ts
import * as A from 'fp-ts/Array'
import * as RA from 'fp-ts/ReadonlyArray'
import {flow} from 'fp-ts/function'
import type {Forest} from 'fp-ts/Tree'

const flattenForest: <A>(forest: Forest<A>) => readonly A[] = RA.chain(
  ({value, forest}) => [value, ...flattenForest(forest)]
)

// (node: NavigationNode) => T.Task<readonly NavigationNode[]>
const flattenNavNode = flow(
  // make the tree
  navNodeToTree,
  T.map(
    flow(
      // make a forest out of the tree
      // equivalent to x => [x]
      // I’m using the Array instead of the ReadonlyArray module because
      // Forest is defined as a mutable, not readonly, array for some reason
      A.of,
      // flatten the forest
      flattenForest
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: wow, there is a lot to unpack here, I am aware of pipe, task for the rest I need to carefully read this article you wrote. Thank you so much for taking the time.